# not showing htdocs folders in localhost

Tags: php, apache, localhost, htdocs

I have problem with my localhost, it doesn't show the htdocs folders when I write localhost in the browser.

I checked the DocumentRoot and directory and they were C:/xampp/htdocs
but still the localhost doesn't show the htdocs folders.

Comment: It shouldn't be visible in the url. `http://localhost` serves the files that are inside the DocumentRoot

Comment: If you wanted to be able to access `http://localhost/htdocs/`, then you would have to set your DOCUMENT_ROOT to `C:/xampp/` (which probably won't make the most sense, because there is other folders belonging to the application in there, which should rather not be exposed via HTTP.)

Comment: Why do you want to access to htdocs...?

Comment: Do you need to have a directory listing?